# I have a text field, which will accept only the NEXT TO NEXT ALPHANUMERIC that is single alphabet next is single numeric FOR EXAMPLE:- s3f4G5A2s3

Tags: regex

html:

input type="text" id="custom_expression"

javascript:

script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"

$(document).ready(function()

{

$(function()

{

$('#custom_Expression').keypress(function(e)

{

var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

console.log(txt + ' : ' + e.which);

if(!txt.match(/^([a-zA-Z][0-9]){3}$/g)

{

return false;

}

});

});

Comment: you need to specify the error, so that we could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

> (([A-Z]|[a-z])+[0-9]){3}

and test it here:
http://regex101.com

Comment: That's not the same as OP. There was a `+` after the  fisrt two `[0-9]` but not in yours.